# WPF XAML Checkbox: Trigger OnFocus to Color Background inside Checkbox square ONLY

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I've been looking for several hours and cannot find how to do this, so forgive if it's already out there...

I'm looking for a way to code an OnFocus change of the background color of a Checkbox using XAML...   changing the color of ONLY THE INSIDE OF THE CheckBox BOX itself, NOT the background of the text content alongside it. When focus is lost, go back to the "normal" color.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Hint, it will take an additional template trigger for the event to invoke a setter that changes the Brush of Background property which is template bound to a Border control within the template.

Comment: I have tried plenty. I am also relatively new to WPF (only about 1 month), having been a web developer for 17 years with some experience in the "old" Windows Forms (and Win32).

I don't fully understand what you're describing, but I have tried a number of sample snippets of code that change the background color behind the text and don't change the color inside the Checkbox's box, which is the opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the ControlTemplate of the CheckBox to do this. You can right-click on the CheckBox control in design mode in Visual Studio and select Edit Template->Edit a Copy to copy the default template to your XAML markup and then edit it as per your requirements.

After you have copied the template you could add a Setter that sets the Background property of the "markGrid". Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationBlend.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationBlend"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                    <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="markGrid" Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" Content="Check" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The last setter in the second last trigger sets the Background property of the "markGrid" to Red when the Checkbox is checked.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow a.m. and respond here. I'm at the end of my workday.  :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. All that happened was that my checkbox disappears from my form altogether... even though I do not have anything doing with visibility causing it to be hidden.

Comment: If you copy the default style to your XAML markup as I described and use this one the Checkbox won't disappear. Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue.

Comment: How do I even add code here? I pasted in my code and am told "too long by 2478 characters"?!